# Перцептивно и сигнификативно слабые и сильные позиции.

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Напишите транскрипцию перцептивно и сигнификативно сильных и слабых позиций (проставьте плюсы и минусы) в словах: ось, испёкший, улучшая, образец, запятнать, осётр, кувшин.

Comment: Откройте лекцию по фонологии, вот здесь посмотрите http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/fonetika-fonologia/fonologia/fonologicheskie-pozicii/259/?n=259&q=463  ,
http://jazykoznanie.ru/388/  . И делайте, кто ж за Вас будет делать...
,

Comment: Что-то я не помню, 3о лет назад были эти термины? Сильные и слабые фонемы были. А перцептивно и сигнификативно сильные и слабые были?

Answer (score 2):

1. Фонология пользуется терминами, которые трудно не только понять, но и выговорить. Сдадут студенты зачет и забудут о перцептивно и сигнификативно сильных и слабых позициях навсегда. Хорошо бы всё это перевести на нормальный язык, тогда какие-то знания имеют шанс сохраниться.
2. А ведь понятие о слабой и сильной позиции звуков - это центральное понятие в орфографии, так как именно слабую позицию занимает звук, который нельзя обозначать по слуху, а нужно проверять (например, безударные позиции гласных). А сильные позиции звуков проверять не надо (ударные позиции гласных).
3. А что делается в фонологии? Там наши ученые мужи  к вполне понятным терминам прикрепляют очень непонятные слова, теперь уже и все сочетание становится непонятным и откладывается в сторону, что и требовалось доказать.Орфография и фонология существуют по отдельности.
4. А теперь немного о перцептивно и сигнификативно сильных и слабых позициях. Рассмотрим, к примеру,  слово "ось".

Фонема О находится в позиции (1) - это перцептивно и сигнификативно сильная позиция (абсолютно сильная). Фонему О представляет здесь основной звук О, который величается доминантой. Для справок: Перцептивный [лат. perceptio — восприятие], в данном случае - воспринимаемый по слуху. Сигнификативный. (от лат. significare — давать знать, обнаруживать) - воспринимаемый по значению).

Но фонема О может занимать и другие позиции - например, в слове "лён" она стоит в ударной позиции после мягкого согласного (2). Это уже "мягкий" гласный О с другой акустикой, но мы по-прежнему уверены в его знаковых качествах (перед нами всё та же  фонема О). Такая позиция называется перцептивно слабой, но сигнификативно сильной. Фонетика звука изменилась, но не настолько, чтобы он перестал выполнять свои смыслоразличительные обязанности.

А теперь рассмотрим слово "гора" - "г(Λ)ра" (3). Здесь фонему А представляет звук Λ , который с таким же успехом может представлять фонему А (трава - тр(Λ)ва).  Произошла нейтрализация фонем в безударной позиции гласного, и мы по слуху  перестаем различать фонемы А И О.  Такую позицию фонемы О мы назовем сигнификативно слабой.